# ODBC error 08s01 when running c# program on new windows server 2012 R2

Tags: c#, odbc

this is the error i get. (i cant upload images so i use puush)
http://puu.sh/fpMqB/159dd58e20.png

I installed this driver: 
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36434

but that did nothing, I still got the same error.

Comment: Kindly add the error you're getting as text here as links tend to get broken.

Comment: Are you Running 32bit application on 64bit OS?
if do, install this:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255
the x86 version, not the x64

Comment: @TomerKlein installed that driver, but it didn't change anything. Got some more suggestions?